# Obtaining an address for servicing notices from my ex landlord

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, landlord, tenant, rules-of-court

I will be suing my landlord about a week or 2 after I leave, and I am wondering if, from a legal perspective, I can still use the same address for servicing of documents & notices, as on our rental contract. Since they (probably?) aren't obliged to keep us up to date with their address after we leave I am in doubt I can make this assumption. The 2nd option would be to use HM Land Registry and use the address that is on there. Which one should I use for servicing of notices?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd imagine that, as long as you can show that you took reasonable steps in finding a valid address, that should be sufficient. Also consider using proof of posting, or recorded delivery. Incidentally, if the landlord were to move within weeks of you leaving, there's no guarantee that his contact details at the Land Registry would be updated in that time - assuming he remembers to tell them that he moved!

Comment: If the landlord is an individual(s) rather than a company, they must be personally served i.e. have the documents placed in their hand and be made aware that they have been served, you can’t send it to an address.

Comment: @DaleM Are you sure this is the case in the UK, for this sort of case? I can't find any mention of this anywhere, and https://england.shelter.org.uk/housing_advice/tenancy_deposits/tenancy_deposit_compensation_claims makes no mention of this either.

Comment: @DaleM - no way. I don't believe this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're serving a notice under the contract, you need to use the method specified in the contract.
If you're suing them, the rules for service are at CPR 6.9: https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part06#6.9 (probably subitem 6), but note 
CPR 6.11: https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part06#6.11.